# How do I use a for loop to display NSArray of UIImage's

Tags: ios, ios4

Hey guys, 
So.... lets say I have an NSArray of images

```
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray new];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line1.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line2.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line3.png"]];
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line4.png"]];
```

Now I would like to load all these at once using a for loop but here is the catch.... I need to be able to set the images as hidden until the user unhides through interaction.

```
 for (UIImage *image in images) {
    UIImageView *line = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    line.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:line];
}
```

But then how to I set the hidden BOOL to NO using another method?

As a secondary question, how would one release *line in the code above?

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to set up your images like:

```
int nextTag = 1;
for (UIImage *image in images) {
    UIImageView *line = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    line.hidden = YES;
    line.tag = nextTag;
    [self.view addSubview:line];
    [line release];
    nextTag++;
}
```

...and then to unhide them you can do:

```
UIView* imageView = [self.view viewWithTag: lineNumber];
imageView.hidden = NO;
```

...assuming that your user-interaction handler is able to determine what line in the UI the user is interacting with.

Comment: Thanks aroth, that might be the missing link I need. I didn't think of using a tag. But the question on how to release all of the images still remains. Any ideas on that?

Comment: OK I have done some testing and as I was first thinking its not possible to set the hidden tab because there is no reference to each ImageView. Am I missing something or should I rethink this scenario?

Comment: @EcksMedia - Just release your UIImageView after you add it as a subview.  The superview will automatically retain it for you until you're done with it.  And you should be able to retrieve an imageView reference by calling `viewWithTag:`, provided you can figure out what the correct tag to use is.  That will be up to your UI to determine, based upon user inputs.  Basically you need some way of saying "The user touched the control at position `[x]`, so that means I need to unhide the imageView with tag `[y]`".

Comment: YES... viewWithTag: thats it. Works a treat. Thanks aroth that is the exact answer I was looking for. You are a legend. The UI for this is all good as I am really just working on some cleaner code to an existing class.

Answer (score 2):

> As a secondary question, how would one release *line in the code above?

```
 for (UIImage *image in images) {
    UIImageView *line = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    line.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:line];   // this retains the subview.
    [line release];                // release line like this.
 }
```

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
**

-(IBAction)btnReviewStar:(id)sender{
    for (int i =([sender tag] ==30); i<36; i++) {
        btnReviewStar.selected = NO;
        btnReviewStar1.selected = NO;
        btnReviewStar2.selected = NO;
        btnReviewStar3.selected = NO;
        btnReviewStar4.selected = NO;
        if([sender tag] == 31) {
            btnReviewStar.selected = YES;
            break;
        } else if([sender tag]==32) {
            btnReviewStar.selected = YES;
            btnReviewStar1.selected = YES;
            break;
        }  else if([sender tag]==33) {
            btnReviewStar.selected = YES;
            btnReviewStar1.selected = YES;
            btnReviewStar2.selected = YES;
            break;
        }  else if([sender tag]==34) {
            btnReviewStar.selected = YES;
            btnReviewStar1.selected = YES;
            btnReviewStar2.selected = YES;
            btnReviewStar3.selected = YES;
            break;
        }  else {
            btnReviewStar.selected = YES;
            btnReviewStar1.selected = YES;
            btnReviewStar2.selected = YES;
            btnReviewStar3.selected = YES;
            btnReviewStar4.selected = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
}

**
```